# Automatically creating conflicting NSFileVersions

Tags: cocoa, conflict, icloud, foundation, nsfileversion

I've written a custom conflict handling routine that automatically kicks in to resolve conflicting versions of NSFileVersion. Now I want to write unit tests for in order to make sure it works. Here is the question:

> How do I cause/create conflicting versions within a unit test?

This essentiall boils down to: how do I cause a conflict without manually doing it through iCloud? Since this is for testing purposes only, I don't care abput using private API or hacking directly into the system -- as long as the result is a conflict reported from `NSFileVersion's +unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL`. Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Max

Comment: There seems to be no public way. I've filed a radar for now: [rdar://12196293](http://openradar.appspot.com/12196293). Any *hack suggestions* would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could patch `+unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL` with your own version that returns an array of conflicting versions:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static IMP __originalUnresolvedConflictVersionIMP = NULL ;
static NSArray * MyNSFileVersionUnresolvedConflictVersions( id self, SEL _cmd, NSURL * url )
{
    // this code just calls the original implementation... 
    // You can return an array of conflicting NSFileVersion objects instead...

    NSLog(@"%s called\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ) ;
    return (*__originalUnresolvedConflictVersionIMP)( self, _cmd, url ) ;
}


@implementation NSFileVersion (Test)

+(void)load
{
    __originalUnresolvedConflictVersionIMP = class_replaceMethod( objc_getMetaClass( "NSFileVersion") , @selector( unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL: ), (IMP)MyNSFileVersionUnresolvedConflictVersions, "@@:@" ) ;
}

@end
```

Is that enough to go on? I might first try this in my replacement "method":

```
return [ [ self otherVersionsOfItemAtURL:url ] lastObject ] ;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an approach I have thought about already. This would, however, still not cause the right methods (i.e. `didGainVersion`) to be called, and there would not really be a conflict, just simulated through one API. But in the end it could be work (i.e. by adding faked Version objects via OCMock).

Comment: You said hacks were ok :) not sure this is strong enough for your testing purposes. Seems if you wrote a bit more code and/or used a separate pted machine you could automatically create actually conflicting versions?

Comment: A DTS engineer replied to one of my emails saying that currently the only public way involves more than one machine. I could use a VM, or just use this hack. Thanks!